# Switch statement over set statement

Tags: c#, switch-statement, performance-testing

I'm conducting a test about ref structs and text-ValueType's 
and have step into this doubt while working in the struct constructors.

Apparently, a switch statement controlling a ref variable with an i-style loop can be 
 faster than manually setting the array positions in the struct's field. 
Im not sure about he validity  of this kind of test in the top-level statement method but

here is the code

```
using System.Diagnostics;

const string testText = $"""
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.  
    Quisque orci purus, vulputate vulputate
    """;
const   int     load_Steps  =  250;
CharblockExample bySetBlock ;
CharblockExample bySwitchBlock;
var watcher = Stopwatch.StartNew();
var results = new List<(TimeSpan tic1, TimeSpan tic2)>();
try
{
    for (int i = 0; i < load_Steps; i++)
    {
        var start_tics = watcher.Elapsed;
        bySwitchBlock = new(testText.AsSpan(), true);
        var ticBlock2 = watcher.Elapsed - start_tics;

        start_tics = watcher.Elapsed;
        bySetBlock = new(testText.AsSpan(), false);
        var ticBlock1 = watcher.Elapsed - start_tics;
        
        Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(bySetBlock)} and {nameof(bySwitchBlock)}: {ticBlock1} vs {ticBlock2}");
        results.Add((ticBlock1, ticBlock2));
    }
}
finally
{
    watcher.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine();
    var overall_1 = results.Sum(element => element.tic1.Microseconds);
    var overall_2 = results.Sum(selector => selector.tic2.Microseconds);
    var overall_result = overall_1 - overall_2;

    Console.WriteLine($"overall analysis: {(overall_1 is < 0
        ? $"{nameof(bySetBlock)}    was {Math.Abs(overall_result)} ms faster than {nameof(bySwitchBlock)}" 
        : $"{nameof(bySwitchBlock)} was {Math.Abs(overall_result)} ms faster than {nameof(bySetBlock)}"
    )}");
}

public readonly ref struct CharblockExample
{
    private readonly int inputtedLength;
    private readonly bool _input = false;
    private readonly char //char spots
    #region Char-Spots
        _0, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5,
        _6, _7, _8, _9, _10;
    #endregion

    public CharblockExample(ReadOnlySpan<char> chars, bool performTest)
    {
        _input = true;
        Span<char> arr = stackalloc char[MAX_LENGTH];
        inputtedLength = chars.Length;
        if (chars.Length > MAX_LENGTH)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(chars), $"""
                The provided char array is longer than the max of 256 chars for this block.
                """);

        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LENGTH; i++)
        {
            if (i >= chars.Length) break;
            arr[i] = chars[i];
        }

        if (performTest)
        {
            int pos = 0;
            ref var _ref = ref _1;
            while (pos < MAX_LENGTH - 1)
            {
                switch (pos)
                {
                    case 0: _ref = ref _0; break;
                    case 1: _ref = ref _1; break;
                    case 2: _ref = ref _2; break;
                    case 3: _ref = ref _3; break;
                    case 4: _ref = ref _4; break;
                    case 5: _ref = ref _5; break;
                    case 6: _ref = ref _6; break;
                    case 7: _ref = ref _7; break;
                    case 8: _ref = ref _8; break;
                    case 9: _ref = ref _9; break;
                    case 10: _ref = ref _10; break;
                }
                pos++;
                _ref = arr[pos];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            _0 = arr[0]; _1 = arr[1]; _2 = arr[2]; _3 = arr[3]; _4 = arr[4];
            _5 = arr[5]; _6 = arr[6]; _7 = arr[7]; _8 = arr[8]; _9 = arr[9];
            _10 = arr[10];
        }
    }    
    public char[] CharArr => new[]
    {
        _0,   _1,   _2,   _3,   _4,   _5,
        _6,   _7,   _8,   _9,  _10
    };

    private const int MAX_DISPLAYABLE = 15;
    private const int MAX_LENGTH = 256;
}
```

that's my result after the full execution:

> overall analysis: bySwitchBlock was 1240 ms faster than bySetBlock

- In my judgement, only setting without checking for any boolean logic or advancing a integer indexer should be faster, its just in-line execution of commands for what i see

Comment: I tested the `CharblockExample` struct from your first revision using BenchmarkDotNet. Using the switch is about 2 times slower.

Comment: @Sweeper , i'm goint to search about the BenchmarkDotNet it seems really usefull. Can you post the comment results as an answer so i can mark as an answer?

Comment: What do you mean by "text valuetype"? C# doesn't support string-types (that's TypeScript)

Comment: `Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(eachPause_s))` <-- `Thread.Sleep` is very imprecise and using it it completely pointless here.

Comment: @Dai, It doesn't support. I'm trying to implement it some way to store text in the stack, what would be really cool

Comment: `rivate readonly char //char spots` offers no advantages over a `fixed char[10]` field.

Comment: @JamesJonatah _"I'm trying to implement it some way to store text in the stack"_ - You can't and you shouldn't.

Comment: @Dai, cannot get sizeof a struct that have an array field, wich is required and a sad thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Testing the `CharblockExample` from the [first revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/76856260/1) of your question using [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet) gives the result that using a `switch` is about 2 times slower than not using it.

> BenchmarkDotNet v0.13.7, Windows 10 (10.0.19045.3086/22H2/2022Update)
>
> Intel Core i7-6700 CPU 3.40GHz (Skylake), 1 CPU, 8 logical and 4 physical cores
>
> .NET SDK 7.0.304
>
> [Host]     : .NET 7.0.7 (7.0.723.27404), X64 RyuJIT AVX2
>
> DefaultJob : .NET 7.0.7 (7.0.723.27404), X64 RyuJIT AVX2
>
> | Method | Mean | Error | StdDev |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | Switch | 363.3 ns | 7.18 ns | 11.18 ns |
> | NoSwitch | 170.2 ns | 3.44 ns | 3.96 ns |

This is to be expected. You are doing a lot of extra work there - controlling the loop, jumping around with a jump table, etc. I also wouldn't be surprised if the jitter can recognise the pattern and optimise the series of assignments in the switch-less code into something a lot faster.

Here is benchmark code:

```
public class Benchmark
{
    const string testText = $"""
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.  
    Quisque orci purus, vulputate vulputate mattis quis, 
    accumsan in turpis. Vestibulum quis sapien iaculis, 
    pulvinar magna sed, lacinia lectus. Donec nec felis nec
     metus dictum aliquet vel non.
    """;

    [Benchmark]
    public CharblockExample Switch() => new CharblockExample(testText, true);

    [Benchmark]
    public CharblockExample NoSwitch() => new CharblockExample(testText, false);
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var summary = BenchmarkRunner.Run<Benchmark>();
    }
}
```

Generally, microbenchmarking code like this would produce rather inaccurate results. Lots of external factors can affect the final result. You should use a proper benchmarking tool like BenchmarkDotNet.